# File is Given a New Name Yet Still Replaces the Previous File

Tags: java, file

I'm creating a program that will store basic sales information for a store and I want it to create a new .txt File for each week to store said information. I tried to create a piece of code that will first check if a File already exists for that week number and if it does it will either allow the user to replace that week's file or create a new file with a week number of their choosing by doing the following:

```
try{
        File fileTest = new File("Weeks\\Week " + weekNum + ".txt");

        if(fileTest.exists()){
            while(fileTest.exists()){

                replaceFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("There is already a file for Week " + weekNum + ". Replace? Yes/No");

                if(replaceFile.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
                    weekNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the week number you would like to create."));
                    fileTest.renameTo(new File("Weeks\\Week " + weekNum + ".txt"));
                }else if(replaceFile.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                    BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Weeks\\Week " + weekNum + ".txt"));
                    itemDisplay.write(fileOut);
                    fileOut.close();
                    weekNum++;
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, replaceFile + " was not recognized.");
                }
            }
        }else{
            BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Weeks\\Week " + weekNum + ".txt"));
            itemDisplay.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            weekNum++;
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {}
```

If I choose to replace the file it works perfectly, simply over-writing the old file with the new information. However if I choose to instead not replace the file and choose a new week that DOES NOT EXIST it creates this new week perfectly HOWEVER it also deletes the file for the old week. I cannot find any reason that this seems to happen so I'm asking:
What must I change so that the program KEEPS the old week AND creates the new week when I select to NOT REPLACE the old week?

Comment: Don't do `catch(Exception e)`, especially without doing anything with the exception. You can hide errors in your code. Use something more specific like `catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
fileTest.renameTo(new File("Weeks\\Week " + weekNum + ".txt"));
```

by the following

```
fileTest = new File("Weeks\\Week " + weekNum + ".txt");
```

Plus, your if test is useless (the while loop is enough) and your first inputDialog should better be a confirmDialog.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, extra points (if I could) for the inputDialog to confirmDialog, looks much cleaner now!

Answer (score 0):

In the case you said "No": You are renaming the current file.

```
fileTest.renameTo(new File("Weeks\\Week " + weekNum + ".txt"));
```

Instead create a new file with the new name and write on it.